# gtk : connecting spinbutton signal in cellrenderer

Tags: haskell, treeview, gtk, signals, gtk2hs

I'am making a GUI with a treeview using Gtk.

I want to connect the update signal of a `CellRendererSpin` to make some actions (update a drawing) at each modification of the spinbutton (before being validated with 'enter').

I tryed to get the widget spinbutton with `editingStarted` and connect the signal `onValueSpinned` of the spinbutton to make the update.

```
on renderspin editingStarted  $ \wid iter -> do
                                 let widcast = castToSpinButton wid
                                 onValueSpinned widcast $ do
                                                          update_the_drawing
                                                          ....
```

When I click on spinbutton to increase or decrease, the update is done but things are **running away** ... updatings are made sequentially very fast and doesn't stop.

I tryed to replace `onValueSpinned widcast` by `onValueChanged adj` on the adjustement of the spinbutton

```
on renderspin editingStarted  $ \wid iter -> do
                                 let widcast = castToSpinButton wid
                                 adj <- spinButtonGetAdjustment  widcast
                                 onValueChanged adj $ do
                                                      update_the_drawing
                                                      ....
```

I tryed to replace `onValueSpinned` by `onValueSpinned` and `onValueChanged` by `afterValueChanged` and it still running away.

I have several questions :

1. Is `on renderspin editingStarted` the correct method to access the spinbutton widget in a treeview? Is there an alternative method?
2. Is there a specific signal/function to make the update once?
3. Is my method to obtain the expected result globally correct or am I totally wrong?
4. Do you have an example in any language (C, Python, Haskell, ...) ?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your whole code (incl. the creation of the `TreeView` columns etc.)?